# Qml listView mirroring layout current Index

Tags: qt, listview, qml, mirroring

I am working with ListView component and I have trouble with `currentIndex` property. I want to do some action on

```
onCurrentIndexChanged:
```

But when I use

```
LayoutMirroring.enabled: true
```

`currentIndex` is not updated anymore. There is no action in `onCurrentIndexChanged` and currentIndex is equal to 0 all the time.
I've also tried to use
`layoutDirection: Qt.RightToLeft` 
but problem is the same ( no `currentIndex` updates when listView is moved).

I've read ListView documentation and there was information, that if you use

```
snapMode: ListView.SnapToItem
```

you also need to add

```
highlightRangeMode:  ListView.StrictlyEnforceRange
```

in order to currentIndex is update properly. Maybe there is something similar for mirror layout?

Here is the whole code:

```
ListView
    {
        id: id_couplingControlView

        model: id_multiCouplingMeasurePopup.p_iCouplingsCount
        orientation: ListView.Horizontal    
        snapMode: ListView.SnapToItem
        highlightRangeMode:  ListView.StrictlyEnforceRange          //To update the currentIndex as the list is moved
        preferredHighlightBegin: id_multiCouplingMeasurePopup.p_bViewRotated ? id_couplingControlView.width : id_couplingControlView.leftMargin
        LayoutMirroring.enabled:  id_multiCouplingMeasurePopup.p_bViewRotated
        //layoutDirection: id_multiCouplingMeasurePopup.p_bViewRotated ? Qt.RightToLeft : Qt.LeftToRight

        delegate: QmlSHMultiCouplingMeasureControl
        {
            id: id_CouplingMeasureControl

            p_iIndex: index
            Component.onCompleted:
            {
                InitializeCouplingControl ( id_CouplingMeasureControl )
            }
        }

        //Need to to something here
        onCurrentIndexChanged:
        {
            console.log ( "onCurrentIndexChanged:: " + id_couplingControlView.currentIndex )
            id_multiCouplingMeasurePopup.UpdateMiniTrainCouplingList( id_couplingControlView.currentIndex );
        }
    }
```

**So my question is**: what I need to do to have `currentIndex` updated while scrolling listView when using `LayoutMirroring.enabled: true` or `layoutDirection: Qt.RightToLeft`.

Comment: -1: **Question is missing:** *What is happening you don't want?* - **No [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**: *I can't run your code, to see any problems.* When I tried a mirrored `ListView` everything works as expected. Please be specifc.

Comment: I have updated my question at the bottom of post.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got the solution!

The problem was beacuse of this line:

```
preferredHighlightBegin: id_multiCouplingMeasurePopup.p_bViewRotated ? id_couplingControlView.width : id_couplingControlView.leftMargin
```

For rotated view I was setting `preferredHighlightBegin` as wide as width of listView itself. That's why currentIndex was not updated. Mirroring the listView had nothing to do about it.

Answer (score 0):

If you had provided a [**M**inimal, **C**omplete and **V**erifyable **E**xample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) we might have come down to the core of your problem.

So to answer your question: You need to do, exactly what you assumed:

- Make the `ListView` horizontal: `orientation: ListView.Horizontal`
- Enable mirroring: `LayoutMirroring.enabled: true`
- Snap to Item: `snapMode: ListView.SnapToItem` <= Actually seems optional
- enforce the `currenItem` to be in the view: `highlightRangeMode:  ListView.StrictlyEnforceRange`

This is how a MCVE could look like, that proves that it works as expected:

```
ListView {
    id: lv
    model: 100
    LayoutMirroring.enabled: true
    orientation: ListView.Horizontal
    width: 500
    height: 100
    spacing: 5
    snapMode: ListView.SnapToItem
    highlightRangeMode:  ListView.StrictlyEnforceRange
    onCurrentIndexChanged: console.log('Current Index changed to', currentIndex)

    delegate: Rectangle {
        width: 100
        height: 100
        color: lv.currentItem === this ? Qt.rgba(1, 0, 0, 1) : Qt.rgba(0, 0, 1, index / 200 + 0.5)
    }
}
```